# why not change year on material datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, material-design

why not change year and month on material datepicker 
[image]
Here I add css and js:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('assets/datepicker/bootstrap-material-datepicker/css/bootstrap-material-datepicker.css')}}">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/datepicker/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('assets/datepicker/bootstrap-material-datepicker/js/bootstrap-material-datepicker.js')}}"></script>

       $('#datepicker_finish').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0 });
$('#datepicker_start').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({ weekStart : 0 }).on('change', function(e, date)
{
$('#datepicker_finish').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker('setMinDate', date);
});
```

Comment: The question is quite unclear. But I think it is about to know **how to** change month and year. Still, there is not enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: [refer](https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/date-picker/#date-picker-example) bootstrap material datepicker

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear
What i understand is you want to know why year picker is not available on material dataPicker

This was a problem with angular material but has been fixed.
Check this link
[Make year selectable in angular material](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5845#issuecomment-363424109)